# Automatically stop SQL Server Agent when no jobs are running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs

I have around 40 different SQL Server jobs in one instance. They all have different schedules. Some run once a day some every two mins some every five mins. If I have a need to stop SQL Server Agent, how can I find the best time when no jobs are running so I won't interrupt any of my jobs?

I want to see running jobs in SQL Server. If there is no job running, then stop the Agent.

**Reference:**
[How to automatically STOP SQL Server Agent when no jobs are running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980339/how-to-automatically-stop-sql-server-agent-when-no-jobs-are-running)